# Trigger a quick animation and then remove the element in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux

I'm writing a dashboard using react/redux that displays information in real time. I have a `<div>` that keeps getting populated with new data, pushing the old data down. When this div is scrolled, I pause the realtime display of data. I want this to also trigger a short animation of a pause symbol expanding and fading out from the center of the screen. I thought I could use [CSSTransitionGroup](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group#high-level-api-csstransitiongroup) like this:

```
...
render() {
  const img = this.props.active
    ? "/images/play.svg"
    : "/images/pause.svg";
  return (
    ...
    <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionEnterTimeout={200}
        transitionLeave={false}>
      <img src={img} key={+new Date()} />
    </CSSTransitionGroup>
  );
}
```

The problem is that the `img` element and the element created by the `CSSTransitionGroup` are always on the page. I want to be able to trigger this animation when the state changes between `active == true` and `active == false`, and then immediately remove the elements when the animation is complete.

Is there already a good way to do this with an existing library? Or is there an easy way for me to roll my own solution?

Edit:

Here is a quick and dirty [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnw7djds/3/). It doesn't really show what I want to do because I wasn't able to figure it out. But basically, when the button is clicked it toggles a boolean in the component's state. An animation should trigger each time this boolean changes. This animation should render the element within the CSSTransitionGroup, apply a class to trigger the animation, and then remove the element once the animation is complete.

Comment: possible for you to create a jsfiddle or codepen demo?

Comment: @TahirAhmed I added a jsfiddle, I don't know how useful it will be though.